# gamma distribution GLMM with negative values

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

Following this post: [If using Glmm with Gamma distribution do i need to transform my data to be between 0 and 1?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47502/if-using-glmm-with-gamma-distribution-do-i-need-to-transform-my-data-to-be-betwe), I would like to know what the concensus is regarding modelling a response variable with a gamma distribution which has negative values (or at least I think a gamma distribution, histogram below).

Specifically, should I transform my data, add a constant, or just go with another method completely?

[image]

(p.s. I'd ideally just use a linear mixed model but none of the transformations made it normal).

Comment: Good news! You don't need normal data to use linear regression, it's actually the *residuals* that we're making assumptions on (and normality is more of guideline than a strict rule even for these). Oh, also, I would be surprised if it was even, from a software perspective, possible to fit a gamma GLMM with negative outcomes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just double checking I'm following your meaning:

The above histogram (and significant shapiro-wilk test not included here) are of my raw response variable. But your saying that its non-normaility doesn't matter?

The only non-normality that may be problematic comes from model residuals of any model made from this response variable?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right! In your histogram, as long as that right tail has sufficiently different X variables associated with it than the other data, it's possible that the regression residuals will look perfectly normal.